# Why can't I get the jquery-visible plugin to work at all?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, visible

[**Complete SSCCE JSFiddle here!**](http://jsfiddle.net/KheKhe/w7eowzcq/18/)

***What I want:***

1. When the page is scrolled down to the extent that the top part of
   page (*heightwise equal to the viewport's height*) is no more visible,
   a CSS `class` (`sticky` in the example) should be added to the
   header menu `.header-menu-container-nav`.
2. Then when the user starts scrolling back up, as soon as the that
   part of the page (*the topmost part of page which is heightwise equal
   to the viewport's height*), i.e. the `.firstpage` `div` from the
   example *I believe*, the event fired when scrolling down should be
   removed and the class `sticky` should be removed.

***How I am trying to do this:***

*Using the [jquery-visible plugin](https://www.customd.com/articles/13/checking-if-an-element-is-visible-on-screen-using-jquery):*

**The jquery-visible plugin  does not seem to work at all.**

I added the jquery-visible plugin in my HTML `<head>` (after extracting the .zip downloaded from here in the project's folder) like this:

```
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-visible-master/jquery.visible.js"></script>
```

**Please tell me what I am doing wrong? And how to get this to work?**

*My Code:*

```
/**
* Function for the header's drama!
**/
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){

    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var originalHeaderPosition =  $(".header-menu-container-nav").offset().top;

    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    var vph = $(window).height();

    var currentHeaderPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
    var deltaHeaderPosition = currentHeaderPosition - originalHeaderPosition;

    if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop){ // downscroll code
        if (deltaHeaderPosition >= vph) {
            $('.header-menu-container-nav').addClass('sticky');
            $('.header-menu-container-nav').fadeIn();
        }
    } else {// upscroll code
        if ($('firstPage').visible(true)) {//*******************
            $('.header-menu-container-nav').fadeOut(function() {
                $('.header-menu-container-nav').attr('style','');
                $('.header-menu-container-nav').removeClass('sticky');
            });
        }
    }
       lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
});
```

Comment: Remove the minimized reference of the visible framework. It's the same code but in a compressed style, so it could be screwing up your references.

Comment: @ElliotM Mid version? What do you mean? and framework? It's a plugin. I am a newb, so please if you can say it in a simpler way, I'll really appreciate it.

Comment: Remove the reference to `"jquery-visible-master/jquery.visible.min.js"`. I apologize, it is a library.

Comment: @ElliotM Just did that. Did not make any difference. :(

Comment: What are the errors in your console?

Comment: @ElliotM I succeeded to add the jquery-visible plugin to the JSFiddle in an external resource, and updated the link in the question. So you can now test it in the JSFiddle I have linked?

Comment: @ElliotM How do I find those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing "." in the following lines which have to be mentioned as class.

```
 $('firstPage').visible(true)
 $('sticky').css('top', 0+'px');
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w7eowzcq/25/), I added raw Jquery-visible-min in your javascript and edited your code.

Comment: First, thank you. I corrected the syntax error. But still, the result is not what I expected. From [this tutorial](https://www.customd.com/articles/13/checking-if-an-element-is-visible-on-screen-using-jquery), _"Passing true to the 'visible' method, will tell the plugin to return true if ANY part of the element is visible on the users screen."_. **I am passing `true` to the `visible()` function, but still** as you can see in [your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7eowzcq/25/), it only **seems to return true when the entire `.firstPage` element becomes visible**. =s